# Send A_ThisHotkey with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following AutoHotKey script that uses [`A_ThisHotkey`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#h):

```
spamLimit(limitTime)
{
    send %A_ThisHotkey%
}

p::spamLimit(500)
```

How comes pressing  <kbd>P</kbd> doesn't send the letter `p` but instead open the following window

[image]

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply looping `p` ->  start the command associated with the `p` hotkey -> `send p` -> start the command associated with the `p` hotkey -> `send p` -> …

To prevent this behavior, you can use the command [`Hotkey`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) to temporarily disable the hotkey. Example:

```
spamLimit(limitTime)
{

    Hotkey, %A_ThisHotkey%, off   
    send %A_ThisHotkey%
}

p::spamLimit(500)
```

Another solution is using `$` when defining the command, [which](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/115657-whats-the-purpose-of-the-dollar-sign-in-ahk-script/) forces the hook in the hotkey, i.e. disallows the hotkey to be triggered by its own send commands and generally most other virtual (non-physical) key presses. Example (one needs to use the function [`StringReplace`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm), otherwise it outputs `$p` instead of `p`.):

```
spamLimit(limitTime)
{
    StringReplace, key, A_ThisHotkey, $, , All
    send %key%
    sleep limitTime    
}

$p::spamLimit(500)
```